# Issue with Regex in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, regex

```
private void TxtName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            string getString = Regex.Replace(TxtName.Text, @"[a-z, A-z, 0-9]", string.Empty);

    }
```

with above code  i can replace the string which **is matching** with the pattern @"[a-z, A-z, 0-9]". But what i need is , I want to replace the string which is **not matching** with the pattern @"[a-z, A-z, 0-9]".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a `^` in square braces. And also I think you should replace commas and make the second `z` uppercase `@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"` this will match all non letters and digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match everything that is not a word, you can simply use the meta-character `\W` which is equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`.